# XRTable in devexpress report with more then 282 rows empties the report

Tags: devexpress

If you add more than 282 XRTableRow dynamically into a XRTable, the XRTable and any subsequent contents will not show in  the report.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that it is always required to call the `XRTable.BeginInit` and `XRTable.EndInit` **methods** *if you modify XRTable.Rows and XRTableRow.Cells collections at runtime.*

As for the height of a table, explicitly specify it only if cells' content is not expected to stretch the cells (e.g. this may happen when their CanGrow property is enabled).

```
public XRTable CreateXRTable() {
            int cellsInRow = 3;
            int rowsCount = 3;
            float rowHeight = 25f;

            XRTable table = new XRTable();
            table.Borders = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.All;
            table.BeginInit();

            for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
                XRTableRow row = new XRTableRow();
                row.HeightF = rowHeight;
                for (int j = 0; j < cellsInRow; j++) {
                    XRTableCell cell = new XRTableCell();
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            table.EndInit();
            return table;
        }
```

then add this table to report specific band i,m adding this to Detail band

```
this.Detail.Controls.Add(CreateXRTable());
```